# Relative depth determination

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I've several images (birds eye view) and I'm to determine if the object I'm looking it is sloped/has varying distance. Given multiple pictures and different view points , how do I proceed to identify relative distance between two sets of pixels in the image?

Monoscopic image

Comment: An image is 2D, it contains no 3D information. There are techniques to deduce 3D information from multiple 2D views of the same scene but these are complex and involve camera calibration etc. Perhaps you can expand your question and add some sample images.

Comment: Note: One of the most used references for this type of problem is [Multiple View Geometry](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518) by Hartley and Zisserman.

Comment: Could you give us some images?